# Simple CORS setup is not working by adopting all means

Tags: spring-boot

The frontend server is running on localhost:8080 and try to do CORS PUT request to the Spring boot server running on localhost:1072

I googled all the possible solution to make the CORS request work.

However, it's only working by using Postman for the PUT request.

Got 401 on the Chrome browser.

How do I make the Spring server could take CORS requests.

Thanks!

Also, curious why Spring doesn't show the exception on the console and always give developers hard time lol

## CORSConfig.java

```
@Configuration
public class CORSConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:8080");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```

## WebSecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    if (h2ConsoleEnabled)
        http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/h2-console", "/h2-console/**").permitAll()
            .and()
            .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin();

    http.csrf().disable()
        .cors()
        .and()
        .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(new HttpStatusEntryPoint(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED))
        .and()
        .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS).and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/v1/**","/articles/**", "/profiles/**", "/tags").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.PUT, "/v1/**","/articles/**", "/profiles/**", "/tags").permitAll()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/v1/**","/articles/**", "/profiles/**", "/tags").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated();

    http.addFilterBefore(jwtTokenFilter(), UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
}

@Bean
public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    final CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
    configuration.setAllowCredentials(true);
    configuration.addAllowedOrigin("*");
    configuration.addAllowedHeader("*");
    configuration.addAllowedMethod("*");
    final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
    return source;
}
```

}

## ArticleApi.java

```
  @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
  @RestController
  @RequestMapping(path = "/v1/groups/{groupId}/articles/{aId}")
  public class ArticleApi {


      @CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
      @PutMapping
      public String updateArticle(@PathVariable("groupId") String groupId,
                                  @PathVariable("aId") String aId
                                  ) {
          return 
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

The 401 reponse is received when the pre-flight check for the CORS request fails. So, it might be that your cors is not setup correctly.When reading through your config it made the following observations :

- If you are going to allow cross origin requests from all domains on all methods, you could remove the controller method level annotation `@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")` as it is already specified at class level.
- You are providing two global configurations for the CORS config. One config with the bean order set as 0 accepts only origin `http://localhost:8080` while that configured with spring security accepts all origin.Remove one and keep either of the two as per your need.

You could try removing the CORS configuration provided in the class `CORSConfig`. You have already provided cors configuration along with `WebSecurityConfig`. You could remove the cors configuration provided in the security config,either way it will work with just one configuration or try removing the below code :

```
@Configuration
public class CORSConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {

        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
        config.setAllowCredentials(true);
        config.addAllowedOrigin("http://localhost:8080");
        config.addAllowedHeader("*");
        config.addAllowedMethod("*");
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
        FilterRegistrationBean bean = new FilterRegistrationBean(new CorsFilter(source));
        bean.setOrder(0);
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedMethods("*").allowedOrigins("*");
    }
}
```